# How to deal with The type 'Foo' in 'File1.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Foo' in 'File2.dll' warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings, pragma

I have the following solution structure:
Project A
Project B (WCF)
Project C (Unit Testing)

I generate a proxy from Project B. The proxy is then included in Project A and Project C.
Project C also references Project A. 
As a result, when compiling I get over a thousand warnings of the type:

> The type 'Foo' in 'File1.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Foo' in 'File2.dll'.

What is the best solution to this problem? I tried using #PRAGMA IGNORE, but I couldn't find the warning number in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best case is to use different Namespaces.

So ProjectA

```
namespace Project.Library
```

ProjectB

```
namespace Project.Service
```

ProjectC

```
namespace Project.Test
```

Then, you can use an alias in your conflict class.

For example, say Project.Library.User and Project.Service.User both exist.

You want to access your library's user class in your service, you could do:

```
using Library = Project.Library;

namespace Project.Service
{
     public class User
     {
          public int GetUserId()
          {
              Library.User myLibUser = new Library.User();
              return myLibUser.Id;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you access your type, fully qualify it (by calling it through namespace(s).class so there can't be ambiguity.

For instance:

- MyNamespace.Foo
- YourNamespace.Foo

So you have same class name, but under different namespaces.

If in any chance you're using the same namespace as in the imported stuff (which is unlikely) then either you or the external code providers will have to change the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I am using VS 2010 Pro. I ignored it for about 10 hours; not just error but errors at complie time. Then, BAM!

All I did was navigate to the `Build` tab and click clean solution.
Problem solved. Be sure, you aren't disposing anything in your using statements that need not be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove reference to your compiled file from Solution\References :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Class Properties, change Build Action from Content to Compile

Answer (score 0):

When you know what you are doing, you can suppress the warnings with Pragma **0246**.

I found the error code by starting a build and then look in the output window.
Make sure you have 'build' selected in the dropdown.